# Intermittent dbus and/or systemd problem on Rocky Linux 8.7

Tags: linux, systemd, d-bus

Occasionally on some of our servers, we seem to be running into a problem that (so far) only a reboot will solve. Symptoms are slow logins and sudo commands. These seem to be related to timeouts on `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`.

Running:

```
kernel-4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64
systemd-239-68.el8_7.2.x86_64
```

(planning to install latest OS patches shortly)

Other details:

- `kworker/0:0+events` is consuming ~100% of its CPU core
- trying to run systemctl commands generally results in "Failed to get properties: Connection timed out"
- `systemd-logind` is NOT running and won't start (logs seem to show similar "connection timed out" messages, probably related to above general systemctl problem
- inordinate number of zombies

Particularly interesting: I have a heterogeneous mix of hardware from various vendors, and so far this problem ONLY seem to occur on one particular hardware model, which makes me think perhaps a hardware/firmware problem. Or, some resource may need to be tuned for that particular hardware, which I'm not aware of yet. It's not totally consistent, though - its only appeared on a relatively small handful of that particular server model so far.

Google has pointed me at a number of somewhat similar systemd/dbus issues that people have run into, but so far none of the tricks that others have come up with to recover the system have worked here - nothing short of a reboot has been successful so far.

Hoping maybe someone has run into this recently and might have found a culprit, or at least might be able to point me at something else to help diagnose.

Comment: Do timeouts occur also if you run `systemctl` as root (in which case it is supposed to use the private "systemd only" socket, _not_ the general system-bus socket)? Does your dmesg or your `journalctl -k` have any mentions of systemd freezing itself? Does systemd react to a `kill -TERM 1` (which should invoke a daemon-reexec)? Does Rocky use dbus-daemon or dbus-broker? Does `dbus-monitor --system` (or `busctl monitor` show anything unusual (i.e. does it show a _flood_ of messages)?

Comment: @u1686_grawity timeouts as root: YES. `journalctl -k` showing systemd freezing: NO. `kill -TERM 1`: NO AFFECT. Rocky does use `dbus-daemon`. `dbus-monitor` does show some errors - things like "UnixProcessIdUnknown", "ServiceUnknown", "NameHasNoOwner" that I do no see occurring on healthy nodes.